# I have problem in doing grid search in agaricus dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Here is my code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package = "xgboost")
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
test  <- agaricus.test



xgb_grid_1 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = c(1:10),
  eta = c(seq(0,1,0.1)),
  max_depth = c(2:5),
  gamman = c(seq(0,1,0.1))
)


xgb_trcontrol_1 <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",                                                        
  classProbs = TRUE,                                                           
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  allowParallel = TRUE
)


xgb_train1 <- train(
  x = as.matrix(train$data),
  y = train$label,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,
  tune_grid = xgb_grid_1,
  method = 'xgbTree'
)
```

when compiling xgb_train1, there is an error messafe

```
Error in frankv(predicted) : x is a list, 'cols' can not be 0-length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x = train$data, y = train$label, trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,  :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
2: In train.default(x = train$data, y = train$label, trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,  :
  cannnot compute class probabilities for regression
```

what should I do?? Please inform me

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. specify correct argument names

`caret::train` does not have a `tune_grid` argument but rather `tuneGrid`

2. you are attempting to perform classification but you are providing a numeric `target`. This is what the error message is telling you:

`You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.`

3. when posting minimum examples here on SO try to limit computation time to as low as possible. In your example this is quite easily achieved just by reducing the search space.

Here is code that should work:

```
library(caret)
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package = "xgboost")
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
test  <- agaricus.test

train$label <- ifelse(train$label == 0, "no", "yes") #convert target to character or factor

xgb_grid_1 = expand.grid(
  nrounds = 100,
  eta = c(0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
  max_depth = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
  gamma = 1,
  colsample_bytree = 0.6,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 0.75
)

xgb_trcontrol_1 <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 3,
  search = "grid",
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",                                                        
  classProbs = TRUE,                                                           
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)

xgb_train1 <- caret::train(
  x = as.matrix(train$data),
  y = train$label,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,
  tuneGrid  = xgb_grid_1,
  metric ="ROC",
  method = 'xgbTree'
)  

#output

eXtreme Gradient Boosting 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 4343, 4341, 4342 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  eta    max_depth  ROC        Sens       Spec     
  1e-04   2         0.9963189  0.9780604  0.9656045
  1e-04   4         0.9999604  0.9985172  0.9974527
  1e-04   6         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-04   8         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-04  10         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-03   2         0.9972687  0.9629358  0.9713391
  1e-03   4         0.9999479  0.9985172  0.9974527
  1e-03   6         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-03   8         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-03  10         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9977714
  1e-02   2         0.9990705  0.9780604  0.9757951
  1e-02   4         0.9999674  1.0000000  0.9974527
  1e-02   6         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9977714
  1e-02   8         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9977714
  1e-02  10         1.0000000  1.0000000  0.9977714

Tuning parameter 'nrounds' was held constant at a value of 100
Tuning parameter 'gamma' was held constant at a value of 1
Tuning
 parameter 'colsample_bytree' was held constant at a value of 0.6
Tuning parameter 'min_child_weight' was held constant at a value of
 1
Tuning parameter 'subsample' was held constant at a value of 0.75
ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were nrounds = 100, max_depth = 6, eta = 1e-04, gamma = 1, colsample_bytree = 0.6, min_child_weight
 = 1 and subsample = 0.75.
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I started R programming just a month ago so I am not really good at R :(.. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Dong Hyuk Yang glad to help. Things can be quite overwhelming when you are just starting. For instance `caret` requires characters/factors as target while `xgboost` requires numerical inputs. Many more quirks exist. Caret is a great package with great documentation and tutorials - keep at it and you will master it.

Comment: Your comment gave me great help. Thank you so much for helping such a novice!